# Reverse geocoding with options - Google API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I make a reverse geocoded call like so:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': foundLoc});
```

I want to add the language parameter to it. If I made a direct post to the Geocoding URL, I would just append `&language=us` or something to the end of it, but how would I do that here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add a language parameter to the script tag when you include the api. Like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ja">
```

Comment: Would it also work if I called the API like this? geocoder.geocode({'latLng': foundLoc, 'language': 'us'});

Comment: I am not sure. I have never tried. The documentation does not specify that option for geocoder class.

Comment: According to docs, @slandau's code should work, but it does not. As usual, Google APIs don't work as documented.